# SQL query on showing a grouped rows that contains all values from a list

Tags: sql, list, match, relational-division

SQL QUERIES

```
TABLE - CUSTOMER
1001,1
1001,2
1001,3
1002,1
1002,3
1003,3

TABLE - PRODUCT
1
2
3
```

The result should be 1001 coz it got all the values match the order table. 
The PRODUCT table might change over time.
I want to find out who have bought all the product from me.
 
Thanks!

Comment: consider adding the queries you have tried already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that `CustomerTB` is a table which has two columns: `CustomerID` and `ProductID`. You need to grouped it by `CustomerID` and count it's distinct product that he bought. (*DISTINCT is not required if customer can only bought one per product*) and should be equal to the total number of product in the `product` table's list.

```
SELECT customerID
FROM   CustomerTB
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT productID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProductTB)
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f274c/1)